# What is the boundary of this set and how to evaluate the function at the boundary?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

> Given
>
> $$A = \{(x,y)| (x-2)y \geq 1, x \geq 2\}$$
>
> Evaluate the function $f(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{x-2}+y$ at the boundary

Should the boundary be?

$$\partial A = \{(x,y)| y = \dfrac{1}{x-2}, x = 2\}$$

or just

$$\partial A = \{(x,y)| y = \dfrac{1}{x-2}\}$$

or

$$\partial A = +\infty$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a graph of the region, the overlap colored purple.

[image]

As you can see, none of the boundary is on the line $x=2$, it is one branch of the hyperbola $(x-2)y=1$. Solving for $y$ we get

$$y=\frac 1{x-2} \quad\text{for $x>2$}$$

The boundary is one-dimensional, and we can use that equation to parameterize it in terms of $x$. There is no boundary in the usual or topological sense at infinity. So in your notation,

$$\partial A = \{(x,y) \mid y = \dfrac{1}{x-2}, \ x > 2\}$$

So your function at the boundary is

$$f(x)=\frac 1{x-2}+\frac 1{x-2}$$

or better

$$f(x)=\frac 2{x-2} \quad\text{for $x>2$}$$

or, if you prefer,

$$f(y)=2y \quad\text{for $y>0$}$$